# собственной класс аналог Console.WriteLine(); C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

у меня друг появился такой вопрос, а как C# создать свои класс + метод аналог Console.WriteLine();  --> MyConsole2.MyWriteLine(); если ето не требует много времени подскажите пожалуйста :)

Comment: Ваш вопрос остался незамеченным из-за редкой метки `c#-8.0`. Если ответ всё ещё нужен, дайте знать.

Comment: А нужно что - полностью вручную весь функционал реализовать или что?

Comment: ну не то чтоб, прямо совсем необходимо, просто в друг появился такой вопрос, и интересно стало, как бы ето происходило ... Но не то чтобы вес функционал,. хотя бы чтобы работал с стрингом, int и если ето не требует много времени, если надо заморачиваться тогда не тратте времени, просто интересно стало...